# Send jquery variable back to PHP and use in mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a complete newbie in ajax, but I read that Ajax is the only way to store a variable from jQuery and send it back to PHP to use it.

As you can see in this example, I have a drop down list populate from a MySQL database:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_gallery";
$execute = mysqli_query($link, $query); 

$results = mysqli_num_rows($execute);

if ($results!=0) {
    echo '<label>The galleries are: ';
    echo '<select id="galleries" name="galleries">';
    echo '<option value=""></option>';

    for ($i=0; $i<$results; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($execute);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($row['galleryName']);

        echo '<option value="' .$name. '">' .$name. '</option>';
    }
   echo '</select>';
   echo '</label>';
}
```

With jQuery I add the selected attribute:

```
$('#page').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('#page option').removeAttr('selected');
    $(selectedOption).attr('selected','selected');
    var selectedOptionValue = $(selectedOption).val();
    var selectedOptionText = $(selectedOption).text();


    alert("You selected " + selectedOptionText + " Value: " + selectedOptionValue);
});
```

[jsFiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/sQ7Y9/)

How can I store the selected option in a variable and send it back to PHP? Never used ajax, so please be as much detailed as possible and patience! :)

Comment: What do you need to send it back to PHP for, exactly?

Comment: The `option value=` with the `selected="selected"`attribute added.

Comment: [__learn jQuery ajax on here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/__](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: I have wrote something like:

`$.ajax({url: "upload.php", type: "POST", data: {selected : selectedOption}, success: function(data) { alert(data); }});`but it is not working!

Comment: @Mark I still don't understand why you're trying to send it back to PHP. Is there another submenu-type element that you need to populate? Why isn't just "submitting the form" enough?

Comment: change `data: {selected : selectedOption},` to `data: {selected : selectedOptionValue},`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol In the dropdown list each element is a category, and I want to use that category in a query.

Comment: Then... yeah, just submit the form... surely?

Comment: Are you remember to get your `POSTED` Value inside `PHP` ??

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thank you! I am really stupid. Now I can get the value in my php file. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sQ7Y9/2/

basically you would need to add this to your code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'your url', //the url that you are sending data to
      type: 'POST', //the method you want to use can change to 'GET'
      data: {data : selectedOptionText}, //the data you want to send as an object , to receive in on the PHP end you would use $_POST['data']
      dataType: 'text', //your PHP can send back data using 'echo' can be HTML, JSON, or TEXT
      success: function(data){
       //do something with the returned data, either put it in html or you don't need to do anything with it
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With some jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "a="+$('#galleries option').filter(':selected').text()+"&b=someval",
  beforeSend: function() {  },
  success: function(html){ 
    $('#content').html(html);
  }
});
```

..and php

```
echo "a = ". $_GET['a'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send ajax request on `change` event then try

```
$('#galleries').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val(); // getting selected value
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php", // url to send ajax request
        type: "POST", // request method
        data: {selected: selected}, // passing selected data
        success: function(data) { // success callback function
            alert(data); // the response data
        }
    });
});
```

In your `upload.php`

```
<?php

$selected=$_POST['selected']; //getting the selected value
//other code    
echo "your result";

?>
```